# scala - foldLeft fill contiguous zeros gaps with sequence numbers

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I have a specific case in foldLeft

```
scala> val nums = List(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
nums: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
```

I need to get the output in by filling in the continuous zeros by sequence numbers i.e 2,3,4

required output:

```
List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1)
```

And I actually need to apply this to a List[(String,Int)]

from

```
List(("a",1),("b",1),("b",0),("a",1),("a",0),("a",0),("d",1),("d",0),("d",0),("c",1),("c",0), ("c",0), ("c",0), ("c",0), ("d",1), ("a",1))
```

to required output

```
List(("a",1),("b",1),("b",2),("a",1),("a",2),("a",3),("d",1),("d",2),("d",3),("c",1),("c",2), ("c",3), ("c",4), ("c",5), ("d",1), ("a",1))
```

I'm trying on the List[Int] as below, but getting error

```
scala> nums.foldLeft(List[Int]())( (m:List[Int],n:Int) => { val p = if(n==0) m.last+1 else n; m.++ List(p) })
<console>:26: error: missing argument list for method ++ in class List
Unapplied methods are only converted to functions when a function type is expected.
You can make this conversion explicit by writing `$plus$plus _` or `$plus$plus(_)(_)` instead of `$plus$plus`.
       nums.foldLeft(List[Int]())( (m:List[Int],n:Int) => { val p = if(n==0) m.last+1 else n; m.++ List(p) })
                                                                                                ^

scala>
```

How to fix this and also apply the logic to List[(String,Int])?.

Comment: @erip.. fill  "0,0.." pattern to "2,3".. "0,0,0" to "2,3,4" and so on, so that the zeroes are replaced with sequential numbers..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m.++ List(p)` is not valid Scala syntax. It should be `m ++ List(p)`.

But you can also just use the operator `:+` .

Example (including both only `Int` and `(String, Int)`):

```
val stringsAndNums = List(
  ("a",1),("b",1),("b",0),("a",1),("a",0),("a",0),("d",1),("d",0),("d",0),("c",1),("c",0), ("c",0), ("c",0), ("c",0), ("d",1), ("a",1)
)

// Without strings

val nums = stringsAndNums.map{case (a: String, b: Int) => b} 

println(
  nums.foldLeft(
    List[Int]()
  )(
    (m: List[Int], n: Int) => {

      val p = if(n == 0) m.last + 1 else n

      m :+ p
    }
  )
)

// With strings

println(
  stringsAndNums.foldLeft(
    List[(String, Int)]()
  )(
    (m: List[(String, Int)], n: (String, Int)) => {

      val p = if(n._2 == 0) (n._1, m.last._2 + 1) else n

      m :+ p
    }
  )
)
```

Result:

```
List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1)
List((a,1), (b,1), (b,2), (a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (d,1), (d,2), (d,3), (c,1), (c,2), (c,3), (c,4), (c,5), (d,1), (a,1))
```

[Try it out!](https://scalafiddle.io/sf/iiXkXkD/3)

Comment: You should be able to roll the `String` back in there pretty easily.

Comment: @erip Edit you are right, I just saw his "required output"

Comment: Markus - thanks.. how do I merge this into List[(String,Int)]

Comment: I get a warning in REPL warning: comparing values of types (String, Int) and Int using `==' will always yield false  in val p = if(n == 0) (n._1, m.last._2 + 1) else n

Comment: I'm in spark-shell REPL 2.2.0 version.. also in the output, the 0's are not replaced by seq numbers.. pls check

Comment: @stack0114106 I edited my answer, now everything should be allright again. What do you mean "the 0's are not replaced by seq numbers"?

Comment: @stack0114106 If you are satisfied with the answer please consider accepting it.

Comment: `:+` (or `++`) with `List` is a _really_ bad idea in most cases, it turns everything quadratic.  Don't use it. Look at Tom's answer for a better way ...

Answer (score 3):

Actually, the method `scanLeft` is more suitable than `foldLeft` for this question.
Here it is:

For `List[Int]`:

```
scala> val nums = List(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)
nums: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1)

scala> nums.scanLeft(0){ (r, n) => if(n == 0) r + 1 else n }.tail
res1: List[Int] = List(1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 1, 1)
```

For `List[(String Int)]`:

```
scala> val xs = List(("a",1),("b",1),("b",0),("a",1),("a",0),("a",0),("d",1),("d",0),("d",0),("c",1),("c",0), ("c",0), ("c",0), ("c",0), ("d",1), ("a",1))
xs: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,1), (b,0), (a,1), (a,0), (a,0), (d,1), (d,0), (d,0), (c,1), (c,0), (c,0), (c,0), (c,0), (d,1), (a,1))

scala> xs.scanLeft(("", 0)){ case((_, r), (c, n)) => (c, if(n == 0) r+1 else n) }.tail
res2: List[(String, Int)] = List((a,1), (b,1), (b,2), (a,1), (a,2), (a,3), (d,1), (d,2), (d,3), (c,1), (c,2), (c,3), (c,4), (c,5), (d,1), (a,1))
```

This solution even works if the first number is zero, @Markus Appel's solution does not work in this case.

Comment: yes.. looking at the help examples for scan functions, this question also fits well...  thanks for opening up a new dimension to solve such cases.. I always confined to use either fold or custom functions...but this solution is really great!..

Answer (score 2):

Note that the `slow` version is `O(n^2)` due to the nested calls to `.last` (which is `O(n)` on a list).

```
def slow(list: List[(String, Int)]): List[(String, Int)] =
  list.foldLeft(List[(String, Int)]()) {
    (m: List[(String, Int)], n: (String, Int)) => {
      val p = if (n._2 == 0) (n._1, m.last._2 + 1) else n
      m :+ p
    }
  }
```

You could get a `O(n)` solution by building the list by appending to the head, and reversing it at the end:

```
def fast(list: List[(String, Int)]): List[(String, Int)] =
  list.foldLeft(List[(String, Int)]()) {
    (m: List[(String, Int)], n: (String, Int)) => {
      val p = if (n._2 == 0) (n._1, m.head._2 + 1) else n
      p +: m
    }
  }.reverse
```

On my computer, for a list of size 32000, the fast variant takes 18 ms, and the slow variant takes 6 seconds.

Comment: hey..Tom.. this also works.. great idea by walking the list once and reversing the list.. I like it..